# SciKit-Learn: Astronomical Error Using Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict an article's page views from title length + the text content of an article.  I've used TFIDF as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
corpus = result_df['_text'].tolist()
count_vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')
dtm = count_vect.fit_transform(corpus)
word_counts = dtm.toarray()
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(word_counts)
words_df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf.todense(), columns=count_vect.get_feature_names())
```

I'm using standard scaling like this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
result_df['_title'] = scaler.fit_transform(result_df['_title'])
```

So I get my `X` as follows:

```
_title  00  000 0002    0003    000667  000709  000725  001 0013    ... última  últimamente último  única   únicamente  único   únicos  útiles  네일_박은경  유니스텔라
0   62  0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 ... 0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   41  0.000000    0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 ... 0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   53  0.000000    0.020781    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.0 ... 0.000000
```

My `Y` (target values) looks like this:

```
0        166.0
1         24.0
2         22.0
```

Now, I try to run a basic linear regression and I get an absolutely astronomical root mean squared error (RMSE):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X.as_matrix(), Y, test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
views_predictions = lin_reg.predict(X_test)
lin_mse = mean_squared_error(Y_test, views_predictions)
lin_rmse = np.sqrt(lin_mse) //value is 770956447401244.75
```

My mean Y value is 1,487 and it's standard deviation is ~8,000 so this number can't possibly be right.  Even guessing the same number every single time would vastly outperform this.

Interestingly, when I use `DecisionTreeRegressor`, I get a seemingly reasonable RMSE of 15053.957646453207 (still high but nowhere near the linear regression one).

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your data structure for X is not very clear to me so I may be missing something, but why `result_df['_title'] = scaler.fit_transform(result_df['_title'])` ? I mean why use scaler only on `_title` ?

Comment: @mkaran I did that because everything else is already normalized

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

The result of so high error is most probably **overfitting**.

The root cause of overfitting is that you have many features (there might be tens of thousands of different words), and probably not so many examples. And with linear regression, any single feature may lead to disastrous errors.

Imagine, for example, in your train data the word "aardvark" appeared only once in only one article, and by some chance the article was by 1000 views more popular than its peers. So your linear model assigned a coefficient of 1000 to the feature "aardvark". And in the test data, you had an article about aardvarks, in which this word appeared 1000 times. Your model gave a score 1000000 to it! But it was viewed only 3 times by some aardvark geeks. So you got an erorr of 999997 on it.

How can you avoid such monstrous overfitting?

1. **Use less features**. You could count the words with `CountVectorizer(min_df=10)` to use only the words that appeared in at least 10 different documents. This will decrease your chances of overfitting to rare words.
2. **Regularize your model**. If you used `Ridge` or `Lasso` instead of `LinearRegression`, you would probably get much better performance. In my own experience, Ridge regression on tf-idf matrix was as good as GBM and nearal networks.

And the last piece of advice. Your target (article views) probably has very asymmetric distribution: there are few very popular articles and lots of unimportant ones. With such a target, the model will probably be dominated by the few top articles. To avoid this, you can normalize your target, for example, by predicting its logarithm or some other concave transform. It could improve your model performance from the ranking point of view (e.g. increase correlation between fact and prediction).